# How do we explain NMR shielding in filled valence shells?

Tags: orbitals, nmr-spectroscopy

It is universally recognized that NMR measures the shielding of nuclei from magnetic fields by electrons.  The electrons *move*, producing an eddy current that produces an opposing magnetic field.

It is also fairly widely said that a filled valence shell contains electrons making every possible motion within a certain range of energy.  For example the p orbitals are added up using +1 and -1 values for angular momentum, and the electron spins are paired.  MO theory seems, in most cases, to have the same paradox.

Now I know you can look into it and find more detailed math for [NMR tensors](https://www.chem.fsu.edu/%7Eschurko/Research/NMR_Tensors/index.html), but at the intuitive level: what is going on here?  (Are the filled orbitals being hybridized, slightly, with ordinarily unfilled complex-valued higher-energy orbitals to permit the electrons to take on some degree of net overall angular momentum in relation to the axis of the magnetic field, or is it something else?)